# React - issue with function returning same values even though arguments passed in are different

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have a function that creates an array of data. It reads:

```
const createMockData = () => {
    /* Please do not refactor this function */
    return [
        createRowData({species: 'Robot', name: 'T-100', Icon: Android, description: "Likes long walks, walking over the bones of it's enemies"}),
        createRowData({species: 'Bug', name:'Barry', Icon: BugReport, description: "Likes long walks, and creating problems in all your code"}),
        createRowData({species: 'Rabbit', name:'Roger', Icon: Pets, description: "Likes long walks and getting to know the inner you"}),
        createRowData({species: null, name: null, Icon: null, description: null}),
    ]
};
```

The 'createRowData' function is external js file that reads:

```
const defaultMock = {
    species: 'Human',
    name : 'Jon Snow',
    icon: AcUnit,
    description: 'You know nothing, Jon Snow.'
};


const createRowData = ({name, species, Icon, description}) => {
    let rowData = defaultMock;
    rowData.id = UUID();
    rowData.name = name ? name : rowData.name;
    rowData.species = species ? species: rowData.species;
    rowData.icon = Icon ? Icon : rowData.icon;
    rowData.description = description ? description : rowData.description;

    return rowData

}


export { createRowData }
```

When i call 'createMockData' it always populates the returned array with the 3rd line 'Roger Rabbit'. So something like this:

```
0: {species: "Rabbit", name: "Roger", icon: {…}, description: "Likes long walks and getting to know the inner you", id: "6be8c1e0-0070-44cd-a17e-c68097ebfcbd"}
1: {species: "Rabbit", name: "Roger", icon: {…}, description: "Likes long walks and getting to know the inner you", id: "6be8c1e0-0070-44cd-a17e-c68097ebfcbd"}
2: {species: "Rabbit", name: "Roger", icon: {…}, description: "Likes long walks and getting to know the inner you", id: "6be8c1e0-0070-44cd-a17e-c68097ebfcbd"}
3: {species: "Rabbit", name: "Roger", icon: {…}, description: "Likes long walks
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of line

```
let rowData = defaultMock;
```

This line just sets `rowData` to point to `defaultMock`. All the assigns later on will happen on `defaultMock`. Meaning you change the default mock with each call of `createRowData`.

What you want to achieve is create a copy of `defaultMock`, assign it to `rowData` and change that copy. You can do this by:

```
let rowData = {...defaultMock};
```

Comment: thank you so much. Yes, that has fixed it and i understand your explanation. Thanks